# How to authorize user's role in client side of blazor wasm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

### Environments

- Asp.Net Core 5.0
- Blazor WebAssembly App (Asp.Net Core Hosting)
- Asp.Net Core Identity (with Identity Server 4)

### Problem

I want to use Role-based authorization between Server side and Client side.

I can login correctly and `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "admin")` returns True in the Server side.

But neither `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` nor `<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">` doesn't work in the Client side. Also `User.Identity.IsInRole("admin")` returns False in the Client side.

How can I get the user's role in the Client side?

### Codes

#### Server.csproj

```cs
// Startup.ConfigureServices()

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;

    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

```cs
// Startup.Configure()

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

```cs
// RolesController.Get()

var userid = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var currentUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
return await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, "admin"); // Returns True
```

#### Client.csproj

```cs
// Program.Main()

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("WebAppIdentity.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
```

```cs
// Test.razor

<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">
    <Authorizing>
        Authorizing...
    </Authorizing>
    <NotAuthorized>
        You are not an admin. // Always here
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, admin!
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

<button @onclick="ShowInfo">Show Info</button>
<p>@infoString</p>

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> stateTask { get; set; }
    private string infoString { get; set; }

    private async void ShowInfo()
    {
        var user = (await stateTask).User;

        infoString = $"Is admin: {user.IsInRole("admin")}"; // Always False
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined in this issue?  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649

Comment: @DCCoder It works!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are currently [two accepted ways](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649) of handling this.

**The first**

#1 Configure Identity to use roles by calling AddRoles

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

#2 Configure identity server to put the role claim into the id token and the access token and prevent the default mapping for roles in the JwtSecurityTokenHandler.

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
    });

// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

#3 On your blazor application use [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] or any other role your app defines.

#4 On your protected resource APIs use [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] or any other role your app defines.

**The second**

#1 Add Class to configure options.UserOptions.RoleClaim on the Client

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace App.Client.Services
{
    public class ApiAuthorizationOptionsConfiguration
        : IPostConfigureOptions<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions>>
    {
        public void Configure(RemoteAuthenticationOptions<ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions> options)
        {
            options.UserOptions.RoleClaim ??= "role";
        }

        public void PostConfigure(string name, RemoteAuthenticationOptions<ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions> options)
        {
            if (string.Equals(name, Options.DefaultName))
            {
                Configure(options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#2 Modify the Program.cs file to call ApiAuthorizationOptionsConfiguration and configure the role claim.

```
using App.Client.Services;
...

namespace App.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...

            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
            builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
                ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<
                    IPostConfigureOptions<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions>>,
                    ApiAuthorizationOptionsConfiguration>());

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This really should be in the blazor boilerplate as the roles do not work without it.

Comment: Tried both. None worked :( I have scaffolded Identity pages, the rest looks the same. Only Authorization doesn't work.