# Authorize with roles is not working in .NET 5.0 Blazor Client app

Tags: authorization, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-authorization

I have a .NET 5.0 Blazor client app and I am unable to get the `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` and `AuthorizeView` tag to work.

[image]

I have scaffolded identity pages as well:

[image]

I am using a custom identity implementation that uses Cosmos Db: https://github.com/pierodetomi/efcore-identity-cosmos

I know that Authorization with roles in the Blazor client project template is an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649#issuecomment-612442543

I tried workarounds as mentioned in the above Github issue thread and the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798061/6181928

...still, I am unable to get it to work.

Ironically, the `IsInRoleAsync` method is not even called after logging in to the application. I have applied a breakpoint on its implementation in the custom `CosmosUserStore` class and it doesn't get hit.

The browser console shows this after logging in to the application with the admin user:

[image]

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddCosmosIdentity<MyDbContext, IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(
          // Auth provider standard configuration (e.g.: account confirmation, password requirements, etc.)
          options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true,
          options => options.UseCosmos(
              "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              databaseName: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          ),
          addDefaultTokenProviders: true
        ).AddDefaultUI().AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

        services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();

        services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, MyDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
            options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
        });

        // Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("IdentityDocApp.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("IdentityDocApp.ServerAPI"));

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IManageUsersService, ManageUsersService>();
        builder.Services.AddBlazorTable();

        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

**App.razor**
[image]

**NavMenu.razor**

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="users">
                <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> Users
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </AuthorizeView>
</ul>
```

**ManageUsers.razor**

[image]

**ManageUsersController**
[image]

The database has the right data in the UserRoles collection. No issues there.

So, what could be the issue? What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

It is embarrassing but my `IsInRoleAsync` implementation in the custom user store was not correct. As soon as I fixed it the issue was gone.

I am only using the following code in the `Startup.cs` of the server side:

```
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, MyDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
            options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
            options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
            options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
        });

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

In the `Program.cs` of client-side I am only using             `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();`

Thanks to @MrC aka Shaun Curtis for letting me know that the issue lied on the server-side.

Comment: Please add your `App.razor` to your question.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis `App.razor` is added the question.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you hitting <RedirectToLogin> in `App` after you return to your app from the log in process? Or what page are you landing on?

Comment: Thanks, @MrCakaShaunCurtis.  It lands on `Index.razor` after logging in with admin user. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Wthd42b

When I attempt to access "/users" which contains Authorize and AuthorizeView tags, it gives "You are not authorized to access this resource." Screenshot: https://ibb.co/SnVnqB9

Comment: See answer for more testing.  It's not an answer, but you can't put code in a comment!

Comment: Do you have `ApplicationUser` defined in your app ? If yes, it should be used instead of IdentityUser. Do you configure Identity Server middleware (`app.UseIdentityServer();`). Do you happen to implement AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory ? If not, you may need to do so.

Comment: @enet I do not have `ApplicationUser`. Already have `app.UseIdentityServer();` configured. Are you referring to `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` ?

Comment: `AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>` See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpC4SfOzDbw&ab_channel=Blazor%2C.NET%2CC%23%2CAzure%26Unity3d

Comment: oh.. I already have `public class CustomUserFactory
    : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>` added in my project. This is inside client project but my problem lies on server end.

Comment: Remove ` builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` and `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();` You already have them, and test.

Comment: `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization().AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();` what should I test after removing this? Lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste this into your Index page so you can see the information for your user:

```
@if (user is not null)
{
    <h3>@user.Identity.Name</h3>
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        Is Authenticated: @user.Identity.IsAuthenticated
    </div>
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        Authentication Type: @user.Identity.AuthenticationType
    </div>
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        Admin Role: @user.IsInRole("Admin")
    </div>
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        <h5>Claims</h5>
        @foreach (var claim in user.Claims)
        {
            <span>
                @claim.Type
            </span>
            <span>:</span>
            <span>
                @claim.Value
            </span>
            <br />
        }
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        No User Exists
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set; }

    private System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthTask;
        this.user = authState.User;
    }
}
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

This shows which roles have been passed in the authentication data in the header from the authentication provider.  This should include role.

### Update

Remove:

```
// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it and got this: https://ibb.co/YjLLPJC The admin role checking call returns false.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Just removed the said line and tried again. Unfortunately, it had no effect. I got the same result as in my previous comment. The "role" is still not a part of the claims list.

Comment: So the problem is with Authentication, not Authorization.  Your JWT authentication Issuer is not adding the role data to the JWT token.  Likely to be the Cosmos DB interface.  At this point I bow out as I have no experience with it!

Comment: I understand. Basically, the "role" claim is not a part of the jwt token being returned by the Server app. Can you please let me know which interface from asp.net identity is responsible for adding the "role" claim?

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis: `user is not null` . I think user is always not null

Comment: My implementation of the custom user store on the server-side was wrong. Thanks, @MrCakaShaunCurtis for letting me know where to look for the issue.