# Blazor WASM .NET-6 Role Authentication is not working for me

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, duende-identity-server

My project is in VS-2022 and using the TAGS below.

Can someone please explain what the [code-snippet reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563303/authorize-with-roles-is-not-working-in-net-5-0-blazor-client-app) below means in the SERVER program.cs file? What is this snippet intended to "do"?
Specifically, what does the "name" and "role" refer to?  I have already created four roles in the AspNetRoles-table and also AspNetRoleClaims and AspNetUserClaims. However, the following Blazor-page condition does NOT work: `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Owner,Admin,Lead,User")]`

I found the following code-segment in a suggestion that I need this code to get the role authorization work.

When used, I get a runtime error "Sequence contains no elements" on the line containing: `options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");`

I am out of my element in knowing what is needed in the program.cs file sections, formerly called startup.cs, due to reading .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 online tutorials to get my project into .NET 6 and WASM hosted. Much has changed from the past two years especially with Blazor and .NET 6.

I welcome questions, comments and solutions to getting role authorization working in my project.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
           options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
           options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
           options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
           options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
        });

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many too smart variations out there.

Try this official doc.

[Name and role claim with API authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#name-and-role-claim-with-api-authorization)

The Profile Service one.

Create ProfileService.cs under server project.

```
using IdentityModel;
using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;
using Duende.IdentityServer.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public ProfileService()
    {
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var nameClaim = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Name);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(nameClaim);

        var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31851633)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ,I just afraid the code here someday will become that codes out there to distract me like recently then. But now, why not.